# Pass compound compiler options using cmake

Tags: c++, cmake, clang, llvm

I am trying to pass "compound" options to the compiler using cmake's `add_compile_options`.

That is, options involving two (or more) flags that must be passed in a particular order and where none of the flags can be ommitted even if they have already be passed to the compiler.

An example would be all the llvm options that must be passed through clang to llvm, e.g., `-mllvm -ABC -mllvm -XYZ -mllvm ...`.

I would prefer not to use CMake's antipattern `set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -mllvm -ABC")` but use something portable like `check_cxx_compiler_flag(flag available)` + `add_compile_option(flag)`.

However, `add_compile_options(-mllvm -XYZ -mllvm -ABC)` fails because the `-mllvm` option gets cached and is only passed once, such that `-mllvm -XYZ -ABC` is passed resulting in an error.

Furthermore, using quotes "" doesn't help since then the quotes are also passed (i.e. they are not stripped), which also results in an error.

What's the idiomatic way of passing these options with CMake?

Comment: First time hear that manual appending to `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` is *antipattern*. And in given case it looks like the right solution.

Comment: Doesn't `add_compile_options("-mllvm -XYZ;-mllvm -ABC")` work right?

Comment: @arrowd no that doesn't work since it doesn't trim the quotes "" so it adds e.g. `clang++ .... "-mllvm -XYZ;-mllvm -ABC"` which is invalid.

Comment: It's surprising to see that CMake got this so utterly wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you observe here is not CMake preserving quotes.

CMake has special kind of strings - a list. A list is a string, in which elements are delimited with `";"`. When you write `somefunction(A B C)` you actually constructing a string `"A;B;C"`, which is also a list of 3 elements. But when you write `somefunction("A B C")` you are passing a plain string.

Now, when you write `add_compile_options("-mllvm -XYZ;-mllvm -ABC")`, CMake does correct thing (in a sense) - it passes compiler two command-line arguments, `"-mllvm -XYZ`" and `"-mllvm -ABC"`. The problem is that clang gets these arguments as two too. That is, `argv[i]` in clang's `main()` points to `"-mllvm -XYZ"` string and clang treats it as single flag.

The only solution i can see is to use `CMAKE_{C,CXX}_FLAGS` to set these flags. As @Tsyvarev said, it's perfectly ok to use this variable.

Answer (score 2):

Starting with CMake 3.12, you can now use the following syntax:

```
add_compile_options(
    "SHELL:-mllvm -XYZ"
    "SHELL:-mllvm -ABC"
)
```

This possibility is documented here: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_compile_options.html#option-de-duplication

Comment: The answer I was looking for. It's surprising to see that CMake got this so utterly wrong.