# How to write my CMakeLists.txt in a less boilerplate form?

Tags: cmake

In the example below I find the pattern `set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} xxx")` very boilerplate. Same case for `include_directories("${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/...")`.

Is it possible to simplify the writing?

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)

set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Generic)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR arm)

set(CROSS_COMPILE arm-none-eabi- )

set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER ${CROSS_COMPILE}gcc.exe)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER ${CROSS_COMPILE}g++.exe)
set(CMAKE_ASM_COMPILER ${CROSS_COMPILE}as.exe)

set(CMAKR_C_FLAGS "${CMAKR_C_FLAGS} -mlittle-endian")
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -mcpu=cortex-m4")
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -mthumb")
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -mfpu=vfpv4")
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -g3")
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -Wall")
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -Werror")
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -mabi=aapcs")
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -O2")
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -std=c99")
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -fsigned-char")
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -ffunction-sections")
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -fdata-sections")
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -fmessage-length=0")

set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} --specs=nosys.specs")
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} -mthumb")
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} -mcpu=cortex-m4")
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} -g" CACHE INTERNAL "")

set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PACKAGE ONLY)

project("project" C)

add_definitions(-DBLE_STACK_SUPPORT_REQD)
add_definitions(-DS132)
add_definitions(-DNRF_LOG_USES_RTT=1)
add_definitions(-DSWI_DISABLE0)
add_definitions(-DSOFTDEVICE_PRESENT)
add_definitions(-DNRF52)
add_definitions(-DAC_ACC_RAW_SAMPLING_FREQUENCY_25Hz)
add_definitions(-DDEBUG)
add_definitions(-DENABLE_DEBUG_LOG_SUPPORT)
add_definitions(-DNRF_LOG_USES_COLORS=0)

include_directories("${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/foo")
include_directories("${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/bar")
include_directories("${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/baz")

list(
    APPEND src
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/foo/foo.c
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/bar/bar.c
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/baz/baz.c
)

add_executable(
    project
    ${src}
)
```

Comment: Lines between `cmake_minimum_required()` and `project()` are more suitable for **toolchain file**. You may add all flags to `CMAKE_C_FLAGS` variable at once, in single line: `set(CMAKR_C_FLAGS "${CMAKR_C_FLAGS} -mlittle-endian -mcpu=cortex-m4 ...")`. Similar for `include_directories`: `include_directories("<dir1>" "<dir2>")`. These are **basic usage** of CMake variables and lists...

Comment: Have a look at `add_compile_options(...)` and `list(APPEND ...)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All values in [cmake](/questions/tagged/cmake) are stored as strings, so you can [`set`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/set.html) your `CMAKE_C_FLAGS` flags much easier as follows:

```sh
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} \
    -mlittle-endian \
    -mcpu=cortex-m4 \
    -mthumb \
    -mfpu=vfpv4 \
    -g3 \
    -Wall \
    -Werror \
    -mabi=aapcs \
    -O2 \
    -std=c99 \
    -fsigned-char \
    -ffunction-sections \
    -fdata-sections \
    -fmessage-length=0 \
")
```

The code above will replace the value of `CMAKE_C_FLAGS` variable with the new string defined above. To check your results, you always can use the [`message`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/message.html) command.

**Note:** the `\` characters at the end of all lines above are used for line continuation. You can read more about it in the [CMake documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-language.7.html#quoted-argument).

The same can be applied to the [`include_directories`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/include_directories.html) command but with [lists](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-language.7.html#lists):

```sh
include_directories(
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/foo"
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/bar"
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/baz"
)
```

The lists in [cmake](/questions/tagged/cmake) are strings too but their elements are separated by `;` characters. When you specify multiple arguments, they will be joined as a list.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, most of your `CMakeLists.txt` is more suitable for a *toolchain file*.

Regarding your questions:

**Compile Flags**

Compile flags can be added via [add_compile_options()](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_compile_options.html):

```
add_compile_options(
    -mlittle-endian
    -mcpu=cortex-m4
    -mthumb
    ...
)
```

Alternatively, you could do what Akira [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46195039/2508253):

```
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} \
    -mlittle-endian \
    -mcpu=cortex-m4 \
    -mthumb \
    ... \
")
```

Unfortunately, you cannot do [list(APPEND...)](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/list.html), because `CMAKE_C_FLAGS` is a string rather than a list.

If you need to pass compound options, e.g. `--section .text=FOO`, please use the latter approach. For details please refer to this question: [Pass compound compiler options using cmake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35365252/pass-compound-compiler-options-using-cmake).

**Include Directories**

[include_directories()](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/include_directories.html) can have multiple arguments, e.g.:

```
include_directories(
    foo
    bar
    baz
)
```

Note, you do not need to explicitly specify `${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}`, because:

> Relative paths are interpreted as relative to the current source directory.

For more complicated projects, please consider [target_include_directories()](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_include_directories.html) as an alternative.

**Miscellaneous**

1. You do not need to put everything in quotation marks.
2. You do not need to explicitly specify `${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}`. Most of the commands interpret relative paths as relative to the current source directory.
3. [add_definitions()](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_definitions.html) also accepts multiple arguments.

Comment: You advice me to use `add_compile_options` is there a `add_link_options` or similar command?

Comment: I've tried `add_compile_options` but it doesn't work for options like `--section .text=FOO` (with IAR compiler). I tried to add double quotes around the expression, but it doesn't work. How can I add an option with spaces in it?

Comment: @nowox, I am not aware of such command for linker flags. Have you tried just `--section .text=FOO` without any quotes?

Comment: I have updated the answer. First of all, I was wrong about `list(APPEND...)`: it will not work with `CMAKE_C_FLAGS`. My apologies. Secondly, I have added a reference to a question regarding passing compound options.