# CMake How to add flags only for compilation, not linking

Tags: cmake, llvm

E.g., I want to pass `-mllvm --color -mllvm --inline-threshold=1000` flags to `clang` in `CMakeLists.txt`.

However, if I use `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -mllvm --color -mllvm --inline-threshold=1000")`, the compilation will be fine, but I will get warnings during linking:

```
[2/2] Linking CXX executable test
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-mllvm --color' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-mllvm --inline-threshold=1000' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
```

What is the best way to append args only for compilation, not linking?

Note: `add_compile_options()` does not work. See [Pass compound compiler options using cmake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35365252/pass-compound-compiler-options-using-cmake)

Answer (score 0):

Are you you are that's how you pass arugments to -mllvm?

```
 -mllvm <value>          Additional arguments to forward to LLVM's option processing
```

Seems like the --color should just be color. But I maybe wrong.

add_compile_options and target_compile_options are the two preferred methods to set compiler flags. With CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS being the old less ideal way. So I don't see any reason cmake would try to use those flags during linking, unless you are passing bad information.

Comment: No, `-mllvm color` does not work: `clang (LLVM option parsing): Unknown command line argument 'color'.  Try: 'clang (LLVM option parsing) --help'`