# Cmake Fails to Link DL Library

Tags: c++, linux, cmake

Below is the `CMakeLists.txt` I currently have, I am having issues trying to get it to build and link with the `dl` library. The `target_link_libraries` statement did not seem to be effective in doing that (it got rid of the undefined reference errors). I then tried adding the linker flags however, it seems to error out with the following:

```
[build] g++-9: error: ;-Wl,--no-as-needed: No such file or directory
[build] make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/FIFO_Queue_Testbench.dir/build.make:86: FIFO_Queue_Testbench] Error 1
[build] make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:141: CMakeFiles/FIFO_Queue_Testbench.dir/all] Error 2
[build] make: *** [Makefile:84: all] Error 2
[build] Build finished with exit code 2
```

I am pretty new to using meta build systems like CMake so if you could breakdown what was incorrect and why, I would appreciate the understanding. Thank you for any help in advance!

If it's of any importance I am on Ubuntu 20.04 using vscode.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION "3.16")
project("My_CPP_Code" VERSION "0.0")

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED True)
set(MY_LINKER_FLAGS "-Wl,--no-as-needed -ldl")
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS  "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS}" "${MY_LINKER_FLAGS}")
set(XILINX_XSI_INCLUDE_DIR "/tools/Xilinx/Vivado/2020.2/data/xsim/include")
set(XILINX_HEADER_FILES "${XILINX_XSI_INCLUDE_DIR}/xsi.h")

include_directories("${XILINX_XSI_INCLUDE_DIR}")
add_subdirectory("Data_Structures")
add_subdirectory("Hardware_Models")
add_subdirectory("Xilinx")

set(XILINX ${XILINX_HEADER_FILES} ${XILINX_LOCAL_LIB})

add_executable("Main_App"             "Applications/Main.cpp"                    ${XILINX})
add_executable("FIFO_Queue_Testbench" "Hardware_Models/FIFO_Queue_Testbench.cpp" ${XILINX})

target_link_libraries("Main_App" INTERFACE "Data_Structures")
target_link_libraries("FIFO_Queue_Testbench" ${CMAKE_DL_LIBS} "XILINX_LOCAL" "Hardware_Models")
```

Comment: I think this is due to passing a list of values to `CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS`, try removing the quotes or putting just a single set of quotes round the whole expression

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35383627/637669

Comment: Thank you both that resolved the issue with this question. I have another question about DLLs but it is a seperate issue so I will post another question. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

#### CMake 3.13+

Replace:

```
set(MY_LINKER_FLAGS "-Wl,--no-as-needed -ldl")
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS  "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS}" "${MY_LINKER_FLAGS}")
```

With:

```
add_link_option("LINKER:--no-as-needed,-ldl")
```

---

Extract for the [doc](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.13/command/add_link_options.html#command:add_link_options):

> For example, `"LINKER:-z,defs"` becomes `-Xlinker -z -Xlinker defs` for `Clang` and `-Wl,-z,defs` for `GNU GCC`.